# Collecting data via windowing doesn't scale

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have flat table with a large number of rows. Some of these rows deemed to be important for some reason. I want to collect certain fields from rows around these rows in a window. I have a working implementation like this:

```py
data = [
    ("s1", 1, "param_1", False),
    ("s1", 2, "param_2", True),
    ("s1", 3, "param_3", False),
    ("s1", 4, "param_4", False),
    ("s1", 5, "param_5", False),
    ("s1", 7, "param_6", False),
    ("s1", 8, "param_7", False),
    ("s1", 11, "param_8", True),
    ("s1", 12, "param_9", False),
    ("s1", 13, "param_10", False),
    ("s1", 14, "param_11", True),
    ("s1", 17, "param_12", False),
]

columns = [
    "studyId",
    "position",
    "param",
    "isInteresting"
]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns).persist()

window_length = 2
ws = (
    Window
    .partitionBy('studyId')
    .orderBy('position')
    .rangeBetween(
        Window.currentRow - window_length, 
        Window.currentRow + window_length
    )
)

(
    df
    .withColumn(
        "neighbours",
        f.when(
            f.col('isInteresting'), 
            f.collect_list(f.col('param')).over(ws))
    )
    .filter(f.col('isInteresting'))
    .show(truncate=False)
)
```

Giving something like this:

```
+-------+--------+--------+-------------+------------------------------------+
|studyId|position|param   |isInteresting|neighbours                          |
+-------+--------+--------+-------------+------------------------------------+
|s1     |2       |param_2 |true         |[param_1, param_2, param_3, param_4]|
|s1     |11      |param_8 |true         |[param_8, param_9, param_10]        |
|s1     |14      |param_11|true         |[param_9, param_10, param_11]       |
+-------+--------+--------+-------------+------------------------------------+
```

However this method doesn't scale for large datasets. I assume my shortcut to move the `collect_list` operation behind the `when` condition is not really happening and indeed the windowing operation is executed on all rows in the background.

There's an other option to filter first, and do a join. But considering the size (~1E11), I would rather not do that.

**My questions:**

- Is there any mistakes I'm making in the windowing/collection operation?
- When the collect operation is inside a `when` condition does it prevent to slide the window over all rows?
- What other approach would be advised in such case?

Thank you for any help.